# Moving MongoCursor back?

Tags: php, mongodb, cursor, cursor-position

[MongoCursor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.getnext.php) has a method to get next object, what is the best solution to access previous items?

Answer (score 0):

[MongoCursor](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursor.php) implements predefined [Iterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) interface and there are no methods such like previous() etc.. To move the cursor to the beginning of the result set, simply use :

```
$object->rewind();
```

For more information about predefined interfaces documentation is here :

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.interfaces.php

Comment: I do not want cursor move to first document, I wand access to previous one, `$object->getPrevious()`

Comment: @Reza MongoDB cursors are unidirectional and cannot traverse backwards ([source](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html)).

Comment: No way. PHP Iterator class only provides the traversal functionality, not the element access functionality. Maybe you would think about your problem; why you need a getPrevious() method? Better question is; why PHP's native Iterator class does not contains a simple prev() method? Because Accessing and Traversing are different behaviours for collections. Read more about Iterators here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator